# vim set spell in any file

Tags: vim

in ~/.vimrc  I have

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex,*.md,*.markdown set spell
```

but when I have open a this filetype file and after I open other file, example :

```
:sp ~/.vimrc
```

this get spell highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:setlocal spell` (or `:setl spell`, for short) to enable spelling locally
in the current window.